# Flutter, AppBar navigation with Persistent Bottom Navigation bar

Tags: android, flutter, dart, intellij-idea, cross-platform

I am using Persistent Bottom Nav Bar package and I want to Navigate to a desired page using a button on the AppBar, however the NavBar disappears if I do it like this. I understand this may be because they are apart of the same class (Working with the example project from [Persistent Nav Bar](https://github.com/BilalShahid13/PersistentBottomNavBar) git hub).
I have tried different ways of routing without luck.

How can I work around this so the drawer and the AppBar buttons would keep the Nav Bar?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
Scaffold( appBar: AppBar(), body: PersistentTabView() );
```

**solution from** - https://github.com/BilalShahid13/PersistentBottomNavBar/issues/171